# MySQL normal query vs Join query different results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm working on a search function which use for product search.

But when i try to use MySQL join it gives different results.

**tbl_product** table have a product which have sku number **pd_art** 42504.

so it should give a one results when i search using 42504

when i use normal query it gives 1 results

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_product, tbl_suggetions 
WHERE
(
    (tbl_product.pd_name LIKE '%42504%') OR
    (tbl_product.pd_art LIKE '%42504%') OR
    (tbl_product.pd_srkw LIKE '%42504%') OR
    (tbl_suggetions.sgtexts LIKE '%42504%' AND 
     tbl_product.pd_id = tbl_suggetions.sgproduct)
) AND pd_bestsell <> 1 
GROUP BY pd_id 
ORDER BY RAND()
```

But when use a join it doesn't give that product as results

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_product tbl_product 
JOIN tbl_suggetions tbl_suggetions 
    ON tbl_suggetions.sgproduct = tbl_product.pd_id 
WHERE
(
    (tbl_product.pd_name LIKE '%42504%') OR
    (tbl_product.pd_art LIKE '%42504%') OR
    (tbl_product.pd_srkw LIKE '%42504%') OR
    (tbl_suggetions.sgtexts LIKE '%42504%')
) AND pd_bestsell <> 1 
GROUP BY pd_id 
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Can anyone help me to fix this please, i really need to use join query because its 20 time faster than normal query execution. Thanks a lot

Comment: You are doing two very different joins (different results.) Which one's result do you want? (I'd guess the second query is the correct one.)

Comment: Try left joining. It will show results including those that don't have a match on your second table. It could be that the join won't work for that particular pd_art

Comment: @jarlh i need 1 results, the correct results gives by first query

Comment: @James thnaks, can i know is the LEFT JOIN effect for the performance

Comment: I'm not sure if it impacts performance. I would say it will have the same performance as the inner join because technically it will read the same amount of rows, only difference is that it may return more rows. I could be wrong on this, I can't say I have had a situation where a left join takes longer than a normal join.

Comment: A way to improve your tables performance would be to index columns in your table. Indexing will make your join faster and also your where clause faster. Here's a post on Indexes that may be worth looking at. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm

Comment: it's working same performance after i index columns, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first query, the a record would be retained in the result set even if the join did *not* match up under the following conditions:

```
tbl_product.pd_name LIKE '%42504%' OR
tbl_product.pd_art LIKE '%42504%' OR
tbl_product.pd_srkw LIKE '%42504%'
```

I believe that when you switch to `INNER JOIN` (your second query), the record which has sku number `pd_art 42504` is being filtered off because it has no suggestions.  One option to retain this record (as @James mentioned moments before I posted), would be to `LEFT JOIN` the two tables together:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_product tbl_product 
LEFT JOIN tbl_suggetions tbl_suggetions 
    ON tbl_suggetions.sgproduct = tbl_product.pd_id 
WHERE
(
    tbl_product.pd_name LIKE '%42504%' OR
    tbl_product.pd_art LIKE '%42504%' OR
    tbl_product.pd_srkw LIKE '%42504%' OR
    tbl_suggetions.sgtexts LIKE '%42504%'
) AND pd_bestsell <> 1 
GROUP BY pd_id 
ORDER BY RAND()
```

If this hypothesis be correct, then for your matching records all the columns from the `tbl_suggetions` table should be `NULL`.

Comment: I used LEFT JOIN but it took around 6-10 second to execute query. but when use join it take less than 1 second.

Comment: @SunethKalhara When you `LEFT JOIN` you have to scan the entire left table, whereas in `INNER JOIN` records can be discarded.  Regardless, the bigger problem might be that you don't have indices setup on the join columns.  Have you created any indices?

Comment: you mean index :)

Comment: it worked fast after i indexed pd_id and sgproduct columns, Thanks a lot, good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Your normal query convert into join. It should look like.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_product tbl_product 
JOIN tbl_suggetions tbl_suggetions 
ON tbl_suggetions.sgproduct=tbl_product.pd_id AND tbl_suggetions.sgtexts LIKE '%42504%'
WHERE ( (tbl_product.pd_name LIKE '%42504%') 
OR (tbl_product.pd_art LIKE '%42504%') 
OR (tbl_product.pd_srkw LIKE '%42504%')) 
AND pd_bestsell <> 1 
GROUP BY pd_id 
ORDER BY RAND()
```